# .net maui not showing text (binding) in label when binding expression has a subscript "[0]"

Tags: .net, maui

I have an application where I show Tasks.

When you double tap on a task you go to a detailpage.

On this page you need to see the live location of the task:
It's getting to data correctly of the API.

Their is a map, this is showing the correct location.
[image]

Between "Laatse Locatie" and the button their need to be the address.

```
<!--Links Beneden-->
    <VerticalStackLayout  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label Text="Live Location" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="21" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
        <model:BindableMap x:Name="map" WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="150" Margin="0,16,0,0" 
                           MapType="Street" IsZoomEnabled="True" IsScrollEnabled="True" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}" MapSpan="{Binding MapSpanPosition}">
            <model:BindableMap.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:MapData">
                    <maps:Pin Label="Fiets Locatie"
                      Address="{Binding LatestAdress}"
                      Type="Place"
                      Location="{Binding Locatie}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </model:BindableMap.ItemTemplate>
        </model:BindableMap>
        <Label Margin="0,16,0,0" FontSize="14" LineHeight="1.5" Text="Laatse Locatie:" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="12" LineHeight="1.5" 
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" 
               Text="{Binding Positions[0].LatestAdress}">
        </Label>
        <Button Text="routebeschrijving" Command="{Binding GoToWazeCommand}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

The code above is code that I am using. If I am debugging and I delete the 0 in Positions[0].LatestAdress and I write back the 0. Then I see the latest address. It's something weird because I use the same object for the map.

CODE Viewmodel:

```
        [RelayCommand]
    async void GetLatestLocation()
    {
        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            IsRefreshing = true;

            var data = await _meldingService.GetBikeLocationAsync(SelectedMelding.BurgerInformation.Fietsmodellen[0]);

            if (data != null)
            {
                Positions = new ObservableCollection<MapData>();
                Positions.Add(new MapData()
                {
                    Long = data.lastLng,
                    Lat = data.lastLat,
                    LatestAdress = data.lastAddress,
                    Locatie = new Location(data.lastLat, data.lastLng),
                    TrackerId = data.serial,
                });

                MapSpanPosition = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(Positions[0].Locatie, Distance.FromMeters(150));

            };

            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            IsRefreshing = false;
        }

        //Other wise give error melding
    }
```

Someone that maybe nows the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: forgot to add the viewmodel data. Added this to the original post

Comment: is `Positions` observable?

Comment: Yes, Positions is also working in the model:BindableMap

Comment: I suspect a possible Maui bug regarding `[0]` xaml vs ObservableCollection change. I've added an answer that suggests workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `Positions[0].LatestAdress` doesn't update when `Positions.Add(...);` runs.
Specifically, I suspect `[0]` does not re-evaluate whenever an item is added to collection.
Possibly a Maui XAML bug.

---

**APPROACH #1**

Set `Positions` AFTER all elements are added:

```cs
var newPositions = new ObservableCollection();
newPositions.Add(new MapData...);
Positions = newPositions;
```

---

**APPROACH #2**

Add a new property, and set it to the contents of `Positions[0]`, then refer to that property:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
private MapData firstPosition;

...
// After adding new position to Positions.
// IMPORTANT: "FirstPosition" is *property* name. Field name "firstPosition" won't fire update.
FirstPosition = Positions[0];
```

```xml
<Label ... Text="{Binding FirstPosition.LatestAdress}" />
```

Comment: Approach 1 is working. 
I think .NET MAUI can be big in the future but atm their are a lot of bugs in it.